# Using external library for java in netbeans

Tags: java

I've got a problem using external libraries for java in netbeans.
To use some specific classes I've downloaded the JLayer1.0.1 zip-file from http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html.
Afterwards I've added this as new library in the library manager and then added this new lib to my project libs via the project properties.

Then when I try to use a class of this lib the first problem that occurs is that it's not possible to fix imports using ctrl-shift-i. 
So I've tried to import the class manually using

```
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
```

and it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what I've done incorrectly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try to just `Right click LIBRARY -> Add JAR/FOLDER`

Comment: Is your problem is solved??? then you can select my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you extract that file(**JLayer1.0.1.zip**) after you extracted it then open that folder and you will find "**jl1.0.1.jar**" this is the actual jar file you want.

add this **jl1.0.1.jar**  file in the project library or classpath

Comment: "+1" for getting what was the problem.